# How to pick up last value from hierarchy in cell using Appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pivot-table

I used the Google App script to create a pivot table which is shown below, but I'm getting a hierarchy where I would be only needing the last value of the hierarchy to display in the column "M".
Eg. Food>beverage>coffee is a hierarchy I want to display only "coffee"
Below attached image for reference[image]

Here is my code

```
    var intCols = {};
var intHeaders = intData.getDisplayValues()[0];

intCols.interests = intHeaders.indexOf("Targeting Value") + 1;
intCols.spend = intHeaders.indexOf("Spend in account currency") + 1;
intCols.campID = intHeaders.indexOf("Campaign ID") + 1;

var intvals = intData.getDisplayValues();
var intcampArr = intvals.filter(function(e) { return e.indexOf(camp) > -1  });

if ((intData.getDisplayValues().length > 1) && (intcampArr.length > 0)) {
// Pivot for Interests
var pivot4 = sheet.getRange("M1").createPivotTable(intData);

pivot4
  .addRowGroup(intCols.interests)
  .showTotals(false)
  .setDisplayName("Interests");
pivot4.addPivotValue(intCols.spend, sm).setDisplayName("Spend");
pivot4.addCalculatedPivotValue(pKPI, formulas[pKPI][0]);
pivot4.addCalculatedPivotValue(sKPI, formulas[sKPI][0]);
}else {
sheet.hideColumns(13, 5);
}
```

[Data sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hWWj2wQ0Ru_WRgIPJfdI6-WCBHJM-7xMssMZvyAt6fI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you show your current script and your attempts at getting the last value? May be a  [Mcve]

Comment: @TheMaster - I didn't have any code of last value but i can share the pivout function code which I'm using for building pivot table

Comment: @TheMaster Edited the question please check

Comment: Can you provide the spreadsheet where the `sourceData` is located?

Comment: @Iamblichus Already added the link above with the name "Data Sheet"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the values in column `M`, retrieving the string after the last `>`.

You could do this with a combination of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)):

```
var interestsRange = sheet.getRange("M2:M");
var interestsValues = interestsRange.getValues();
var newValues = interestsValues.map(value => {
  if (value[0].includes(" > ")) return [value[0].split(" > ").reverse()[0]];
  else return value;
});
interestsRange.setValues(newValues);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Lamblichus this helped me, but how if i want to pick the column using column header. here it is a range.

Comment: @SaiK You're welcome. Do you mean not specifying the `M` column, but looking for the column whose header is `Interests`? In that case, you could do: ` var column = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].indexOf("Interests");
  var interestsRange = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow() - 1);`. If that's not what you want, I'd suggest you to post another question to handle this issue.

Comment: @Lamblichus I'm trying to read the above (M:M) total column using its header name(Targeting Value) instead of a range.

Comment: @SaiK Yes, I'm not sure what do you want to do, but if I understand your request correctly, that's what my suggestion is doing, even though the header name in this case is called `Interests`, and I forgot to add 1 to the found index (columns are 1-indexed, and arrays are 0-indexed).

Comment: @Lamblichus - It worked for me  (picking column data with a header name), but my problem is sometimes the column doesn't contain hierarchy (">") in that case code is unable to map and split the values and ending up with error.

Comment: @SaiK In that case you just have to first check whether each element contains `" > "`. I updated my answer with this modification.

Comment: @Lamblichus - Thanks for the help but my script throwing this error
 " TypeError: value[0].includes is not a function" .

Comment: ` var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl);
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Interests-Data"); 
     var column = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].indexOf("Targeting Value"); 
  column++;
 var interestsRange = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow() - 1);
     var interestsValues = interestsRange.getValues();
     var newValues = interestsValues.map(value => {
        if (value[0].includes(" > ")) return [value[0].split(" > ").reverse()[0]];
        else return value;
      });
      interestsRange.setValues(newValues);`

Comment: @SaiK I cannot reproduce this. I'm not getting any error when using the code you provided in the previous comment. But anyway, I see you modified your script in the spreadsheet to check if `value[0]` is a string. With this, I think this error won't show up again.

Comment: @Lamblichus Checked value[0] is a string resolved the error, Thank you so much for your help all the time.